# css issue with firefox

Tags: css

I've an issue with loading CSS correctly on FireFox. The page content is loaded from Db correctly. When it lands on show stage, the page is messed up in Firefox and works fine in Chrome, IE. I had the same issue with chrome which I fixed by adding.

```
#myTable { width: 100%;overflow:hidden; }
```

But this never help with FF. I suspect this happen when Firefox tries to load javascript, then CSS gets messed up. Here is my CSS and my demo page

http://sudanesetweeps.com/dev/index.php

```
/*

*/


body {
    background: #282425 url(../images/background.jpg) no-repeat top center;
    font-size:12px;
}

#myTable { width: 100%;overflow:hidden; }
.wrapper {
    position:relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 852px;
    padding: 25px 0;
}

/* header */
.header .logo {
    margin-bottom: 21px;
}
.header ul.nav {
    position:relative;
    list-style: none;
    margin:0;padding:0;
    color: #fcd770;
    background: url(../images/menu.png) no-repeat top left;
    overflow:hidden;
    height: 46px;
    font-size:15px;
}
    .header ul.nav li {
        float:left;
        position:relative;
        margin: 15px 0 0 20px;
    }
    .header ul.nav li a{
        color: #fcd770;
        text-decoration:none;
        font-weight:bold;
    }
.header .header_twitter {
    position:relative;
    height: 260px;
    background: url(../images/header_bg.png) no-repeat top left;
    color: #fff;
}
    .header .header_twitter .singin_twitter {
        position:absolute;
        bottom: 40px;
        right: 55px;
    }

/* middle */
.middle {
    position:relative;
    margin: 30px 0;
}
.middle a{
    color: #000;
}
    .middle .row_top {
        background: url(../images/table_top.png) no-repeat top left;
        overflow:hidden;
        color: #fcd770;
    }
    .middle .row {
        overflow:hidden;
        background: url(../images/table_middle.png) no-repeat top left;
        color: #000;
    }
    .middle .row_top .col1,
    .middle .row_top .col2,
    .middle .row_top .col3,
    .middle .row_top .col4,
    .middle .row_top .col5,
    .middle .row_top .col6,
    .middle .row_top .col7,
    .middle .row_top .col8{
        float:left;
        padding: 20px 0 18px;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .middle .row .col1,
    .middle .row .col5,
    .middle .row .col3,
    .middle .row .col4,
    .middle .row .col6,
    .middle .row .col7,
    .middle .row .col8{
        float:left;
        padding: 20px 0 0 0;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .middle .row .col2{
        padding: 7px 0 8px 0;
        float:left;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .middle .row .col1,
    .middle .row_top .col1{
        width: 98px;
    }
    .middle .row .col2,
    .middle .row_top .col2{
        width: 102px;
    }
    .middle .row .col3,
    .middle .row_top .col3{
        width: 146px;
    }
    .middle .row .col4,
    .middle .row_top .col4{
        width: 150px;
    }
    .middle .row .col5,
    .middle .row_top .col5{
        width:76px;
    }
    .middle .row .col6,
    .middle .row_top .col6{
        width:73px;
    }
    .middle .row .col7,
    .middle .row_top .col7{
        width:118px;
    }
    .middle .row .col8,
    .middle .row_top .col8{
        width:87px;
    }
    .middle .last {
        background: url(../images/table_bottom.png) no-repeat top left;
    }




/* footer */
.footer {

}
    .footer_top {
        height: 17px;
        background: url(../images/footer_top.png) no-repeat top left;
    }
    .footer_bottom {
        height: 17px;
        background: url(../images/footer_bottom.png) no-repeat top left;
    }
    .footer_content {
        background: #2b7fc3;
        color: #fff;
        width:851px;
        font-size:12px;
        text-align:center;
    }
        .footer_content a {
            color: #fcd770;
            font-size: 12px;
            text-decoration:none;

        }
```

Comment: thanks for ur suggestion , but its fix it in FF and messed up now in chrome also in FF the row text is not in place any more –

Comment: As an aside, rather than controlling the width of every column of the table using CSS, if you didn't do this, the browser would render the table, wrapping as needed and should come out with a flexible layout of the columns based on their contents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by combination of the `<colgroup>` in your html and the css for your table elements. The simplest fix is to delete the `<colgroup>` as it is not needed in this case. Your site will still look as you want it to.

**EDIT :** On further investigation it appears `<colgroup>` is being generated by your JavaScript. If you disable JavaScript and refresh your page in Firefox you will see it is fine. I believe it is being generated by *jquery.tablesorter.min.js*.

I would suggest using a different table pagination plugin. I don't have much experience with table pagination, but I would google and try out some of the available plugins. This [one](http://www.datatables.net/) looks interesting.

Comment: thanks for ur suggestion , but its fix it in FF and messed up now in chrome also in FF the row text is not in place any more

Comment: @marco: I looked at the test site after your changes and it didn't look like you had deleted the `<colgroup>` in the html as I suggested. And also there appeared to have been css changes as well. All you needed to do was remove the `<colgroup>` from the html.

Comment: in my html there is no <colgroup>

Comment: @marco: One of your JavaScript files is generating it in your html. If you disable JavaScript and refresh your page in Firefox you will see it is fine. I think it is being generated by *jquery.tablesorter.min.js*. Try using a different table pagination plugin.

Comment: ok i did it and removed  <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>

Comment: any suggestion of another table pagination plugin wont cas more bugs ?

Comment: @marco: Happy I could help. You should probably remove `<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js"></script>` as well. I don't have much experience with table pagination. But I would just suggest googling and trying out some options. This [one](http://www.datatables.net/) looks interesting.